# Advantages of format over concatenation

Tags: java, concatenation, string-formatting

I'm using Java, and I was wondering if there is any advantage to using format over simple concatenation.

I would either format like this:
`a = String.format("%s/hi", b);`

or like this: 
`a = (b + "/hi");`

Is there any advantage (other than cleanliness) of using one over the other?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I searched for "format over concatenation" and I couldn't see anything relevant to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format can handle quite complex patterns and formatting, if you need them.  I would personally go for readability over any perceived "performance" benefits for anything other than code used in a large loop. Who cares if your method creates a couple of objects that get garbage collected soon afterwards anyway?

Answer (score 2):

It is better practice to use `String.format` over `String.concat`.

`String.format()` is more than just concatenating strings. For example, you can display numbers is a specific locale using `String.format()`.

However, if you don't care about localization, functionally, there is no difference. Maybe one is faster than the other, but in most cases it will be negligible.

Comment: I thought your response was perfectly acceptable and informative. +1!

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but provided I don't want to display anything in a specific manner, there's no harm in using String.concat?

Comment: @JamesMonger- it was for whoever `downvoted`. Nevertheless, it all drills down to personal taste. You can use anything you want to, `format` or `concat`.

Answer (score 1):

Only one String will be created in the following line,

```
a = String.format("%s/hi", b);
```

More than One String is being created in the following line

```
a = (b + "/hi");
```